# Convert abstract StatelessWidget to abstract StatefulWidget

Tags: flutter, dart

How can I convert `abstract MyStatelessWidget` to a `StatefulWidget` widget?

```dart
abstract class MyStatelessWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container();//Some abstraction here
  }
}

abstract class MyWidget extends MyStatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: [
        Placeholder(),
        super.build(context),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

my `MyStatelessWidget` contains many UI abstraction, including animation scroll listening and ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I vote down: Because `StatefulWidget` and `StatelessWidget` is different and you use wrong function of `StatelessWidget`. You can convert `StatelessWidget` to `StatefulWidget`.

Your answer:

```
abstract class MyStatefulWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  MyState createState();
}
abstract class MyState<T extends MyStatefulWidget> extends State<T> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container();//Some abstraction here
  }
}

abstract class MyWidget extends MyStatefulWidget {}

abstract class MyCurrentState extends MyState<MyWidget> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: [
        Placeholder(),
        super.build(context),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```